# Not getting any data in trace file for sending file using tcp in ns3

Tags: c++, tcp, ns-3, lte, tcpsocket

Following is the code i have written in ns3 for sending files using TCP. i have use mobility model and packetsinkhelper class along with bulksendHelper lass. Following Code is successfully build and created trace file but  generated  trace files shows empty.

```
#include "ns3/lte-helper.h"
#include "ns3/epc-helper.h"
#include "ns3/core-module.h"
#include "ns3/network-module.h"
#include "ns3/ipv4-global-routing-helper.h"
#include "ns3/internet-module.h"
#include "ns3/mobility-module.h"
#include "ns3/lte-module.h"
#include "ns3/applications-module.h"
#include "ns3/point-to-point-helper.h"
#include "ns3/config-store.h"
#include "ns3/packet-sink.h"
//#include "ns3/gtk-config-store.h"

using namespace ns3;

/**
 * Sample simulation script for LTE+EPC. It instantiates several eNodeB,
 * attaches one UE per eNodeB starts a flow for each UE to  and from a remote host.
 * It also  starts yet another flow between each UE pair.
 */

int
main (int argc, char *argv[])
{

  uint16_t numberOfNodes = 10;
  double simTime = 1.1;
  double distance = 60.0;
  uint32_t maxBytes = 0;

  // Command line arguments
  CommandLine cmd;
  cmd.AddValue("numberOfNodes", "Number of eNodeBs + UE pairs", numberOfNodes);
   cmd.AddValue("simTime", "Total duration of the simulation [s])", simTime);
  cmd.AddValue("distance", "Distance between eNBs [m]", distance);
  cmd.AddValue ("maxBytes","Total number of bytes for application to send", maxBytes); 
  cmd.Parse(argc, argv);

  Ptr<LteHelper> lteHelper = CreateObject<LteHelper> ();
  Ptr<PointToPointEpcHelper>  epcHelper =  CreateObject<PointToPointEpcHelper> ();
  lteHelper->SetEpcHelper (epcHelper);

  ConfigStore inputConfig;
  inputConfig.ConfigureDefaults();

  // parse again so you can override default values from the command line
  cmd.Parse(argc, argv);

  Ptr<Node> pgw = epcHelper->GetPgwNode ();

   // Create a single RemoteHost
  NodeContainer remoteHostContainer;
  remoteHostContainer.Create (1);
  Ptr<Node> remoteHost = remoteHostContainer.Get (0);
  InternetStackHelper internet;
  internet.Install (remoteHostContainer);

  // Create the Internet
  PointToPointHelper p2ph;
  p2ph.SetDeviceAttribute ("DataRate", DataRateValue (DataRate ("100Gb/s")));
  p2ph.SetDeviceAttribute ("Mtu", UintegerValue (1500));
  p2ph.SetChannelAttribute ("Delay", TimeValue (Seconds (0.010)));
  NetDeviceContainer internetDevices = p2ph.Install (pgw, remoteHost);
  Ipv4AddressHelper ipv4h;
  ipv4h.SetBase ("1.0.0.0", "255.0.0.0");
  Ipv4InterfaceContainer internetIpIfaces = ipv4h.Assign (internetDevices);
  // interface 0 is localhost, 1 is the p2p device
  Ipv4Address remoteHostAddr = internetIpIfaces.GetAddress (1);

  Ipv4StaticRoutingHelper ipv4RoutingHelper;
  Ptr<Ipv4StaticRouting> remoteHostStaticRouting = ipv4RoutingHelper.GetStaticRouting (remoteHost->GetObject<Ipv4> ());
  remoteHostStaticRouting->AddNetworkRouteTo (Ipv4Address ("7.0.0.0"), Ipv4Mask ("255.0.0.0"), 1);

  NodeContainer ueNodes;
  NodeContainer enbNodes;
  enbNodes.Create(numberOfNodes);
  ueNodes.Create(numberOfNodes);

  // Install Mobility Model
  Ptr<ListPositionAllocator> positionAlloc =  CreateObject<ListPositionAllocator> ();
  for (uint16_t i = 0; i < numberOfNodes; i++)
    {
      positionAlloc->Add (Vector(distance * i, 0, 0));
    }
  MobilityHelper mobility;
  mobility.SetMobilityModel("ns3::ConstantPositionMobilityModel");
  mobility.SetPositionAllocator(positionAlloc);
  mobility.Install(enbNodes);
  mobility.Install(ueNodes);

  // Install LTE Devices to the nodes
  NetDeviceContainer enbLteDevs = lteHelper->InstallEnbDevice (enbNodes);
  NetDeviceContainer ueLteDevs = lteHelper->InstallUeDevice (ueNodes);

  // Install the IP stack on the UEs
  internet.Install (ueNodes);
  Ipv4InterfaceContainer ueIpIface;
  ueIpIface = epcHelper->AssignUeIpv4Address (NetDeviceContainer (ueLteDevs));
  // Assign IP address to UEs, and install applications
  for (uint32_t u = 0; u < ueNodes.GetN (); ++u)
    {
      Ptr<Node> ueNode = ueNodes.Get (u);
      // Set the default gateway for the UE
      Ptr<Ipv4StaticRouting> ueStaticRouting = ipv4RoutingHelper.GetStaticRouting (ueNode->GetObject<Ipv4> ());
      ueStaticRouting->SetDefaultRoute (epcHelper->GetUeDefaultGatewayAddress (), 1);
    }

  // Attach one UE per eNodeB
  for (uint16_t i = 0; i < numberOfNodes; i++)
      {
        lteHelper->Attach (ueLteDevs.Get(i), enbLteDevs.Get(i));
        // side effect: the default EPS bearer will be activated
      }


  // Install and start applications on UEs and remote host
  uint16_t dlPort = 1234;
  uint16_t ulPort = 2000;
  uint16_t otherPort = 3000;
  ApplicationContainer clientApps;
  ApplicationContainer serverApps;
  for (uint32_t u = 0; u < ueNodes.GetN (); ++u)
    {
      ++ulPort;
      ++otherPort;
      PacketSinkHelper dlPacketSinkHelper ("ns3::TcpSocketFactory", InetSocketAddress (Ipv4Address::GetAny (), dlPort));
      PacketSinkHelper ulPacketSinkHelper ("ns3::TcpSocketFactory", InetSocketAddress (Ipv4Address::GetAny (), ulPort));
      PacketSinkHelper packetSinkHelper ("ns3::TcpSocketFactory", InetSocketAddress (Ipv4Address::GetAny (), otherPort));
      serverApps.Add (dlPacketSinkHelper.Install (ueNodes.Get(u)));
      serverApps.Add (ulPacketSinkHelper.Install (remoteHost));
      serverApps.Add (packetSinkHelper.Install (ueNodes.Get(u)));

      BulkSendHelper dlClient ("ns3::TcpSocketFactory", InetSocketAddress(ueIpIface.GetAddress (u), dlPort));
      dlClient.SetAttribute ("MaxBytes", UintegerValue(maxBytes));

      BulkSendHelper ulClient  ("ns3::TcpSocketFactory",InetSocketAddress(remoteHostAddr, ulPort));
      ulClient.SetAttribute ("MaxBytes", UintegerValue(maxBytes));

      BulkSendHelper client ("ns3::TcpSocketFactory",InetSocketAddress(ueIpIface.GetAddress (u), otherPort));
      client.SetAttribute ("MaxBytes", UintegerValue(maxBytes));

      clientApps.Add (dlClient.Install (remoteHost));
      clientApps.Add (ulClient.Install (ueNodes.Get(u)));
      if (u+1 < ueNodes.GetN ())
        {
          clientApps.Add (client.Install (ueNodes.Get(u+1)));
        }
      else
        {
          clientApps.Add (client.Install (ueNodes.Get(0)));
        }
    }
  serverApps.Start (Seconds (0.01));
  clientApps.Start (Seconds (0.01));

  serverApps.Stop (Seconds (10.0));
  clientApps.Stop (Seconds (10.0));


  lteHelper->EnableTraces ();
  // Uncomment to enable PCAP tracing
  //p2ph.EnablePcapAll("lena-epc-first");

  Simulator::Stop(Seconds(simTime));
  Simulator::Run();

  /*GtkConfigStore config;
  config.ConfigureAttributes();*/

  Simulator::Destroy();
  return 0;

}
```

Please look into above code and suggest if anything is missing to obtained output in trace file.

Comment: the posted code is NOT C.  Please correct the list of 'tags'